# Getting pages indexed in Kik browser

Tags: kik

I'm having trouble getting pages to show up in the NEW tab and in the Optimized for Kik search results.

All my pages have the required title, meta description, canonical and script tag served if the user-agent contains the string "kik".

Here is an example of a page that isn't being indexed.

http://playcanv.as/p/MW862amA

The pages have been correctly set up for around a week and still aren't showing up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Kik browser shows a loading screen on top of your website until the `window.onload` event has fired. If the website takes too long to load the user is presented with an error screen.

Testing locally, http://playcanv.as/p/MW862amA downloaded roughly 5MB before `window.onload` and took roughly 30 seconds to get there. I'm betting the search index isn't let it in because of this.

So the fix is simply deferring expensive network requests until after `window.onload`. The easiest solution is to wrap your network calls in `kik.ready(function(){})`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to fire onload before we start loading. I'm not convinced that is the problem, because other pages have a much smaller download (~600k) and load much more quickly.